# Numbers above are the same as numpad

Tags: customization, axis

I want to change my hotkeys for viewing different axis in blender, but I am experiencing some difficulties. When I change the "view axis" hotkey in my blender preferences to other numpad numbers it all works normally, but when I save it as a "start up file" it stops working correctly after opening a start up file.

In the new file, blender sees the normal numbers now as numpad numbers (the ones on the top row of a keyboard). This means when I try to edit the keymap and I press the normal number "1" now, it says I pressed the "numpad 1". The problem here is when I am in edit mode, the shortcut selection tool for points, edges and faces doesn't work anymore, because blender thinks I'm pressing the numpad numbers.

When I reset it and load factory settings everything works again, but I really want to change the shortcuts for viewing an axis. I hope the problem is clear and would love to hear from you.

Greetings,
Kevin Schipper

Comment: Did you try using Save Preferences (bottom-left 'hamburger' icon under Edit > Preferences) after changing the hotkeys?

Comment: It sounds like you may have turned on emulate numpad.